# javascript conditional operator issue

Tags: javascript

Hello sorry if this is a duplicate question but I was wondering if someone could help me out with my code I don't know what i'm missing i'm supposed to create a page that the user enters a age and it returns the result of the ticket prices.

Under age 5 entry is free
Between ages 5 and 12 (inclusive) a child’s ticket costs $5.00
Older than 12 an adult ticket costs $9.00

Here's my code:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var age; 
    var older;
    var young;
    
    age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    
    
    older = (age >= 13) ? "$9":"$5";
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = older + " movie";
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Input your age and click the button:</p>

<input id="age" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p> Under age 5 entry is free

Between ages 5 and 12 (inclusive) a childís ticket costs $5.00

Older than 12 an adult ticket costs $9.00 </p>
<body>
```

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: And what's the issure?

Comment: @stybl The "free" option is not evaluated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add check for `age < 5` at beginning of conditional operator

```js
function myFunction() {
    var age; 
    var older;
    var young;
    
    age = document.getElementById("age").value;       
    
    older = age < 5 ? "free" : (age >= 13) ? "$9" : "$5";
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = older + " movie";
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Input your age and click the button:</p>

<input id="age" />

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
<p> Under age 5 entry is free

Between ages 5 and 12 (inclusive) a childís ticket costs $5.00

Older than 12 an adult ticket costs $9.00 </p>
<body>
```

Comment: To be more understandable (with multiple tests and conditional operator, I allway add some `()` for each condition and for child conditional operation: `older = (age < 5) ? "Free" : ((age >= 13) ? "$9" : "$5")`

Answer (score 0):

You can very easily achieve what you want by chaining ifs:

```
function myFunction() {
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var price;

    if (age >= 13) {
        price = "$9";
    }
    else if (age >= 5) {
        price = "$5";
    }
    else {
        price = "Free";
    }

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = price + " movie";
}
```

Or, if you really, *really* want to use shorthand:

```
function myFunction() {
    var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var price = (age >= 13) ? "$9" : ((age < 5) ? "Free" : "$5");

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = price + " movie";
}
```

The parentheses are optional. I've only included them to make it clear what is going on.

Comment: You have to switch the 5$ price with the Free result on the first example

Comment: Whoops. Edited my answer.